# Minecraft Skyblock Nether mobs spawning slowly/low cap

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Skyblock v4.02 from here: https://www.planetminecraft.com/project/skyblock-4/
I have a basic nether fortress farm that just has one-block-wide spawning rooms where I can hit the mobs' feet. However, mob spawning is super slow in the nether, compared to the overworld. It takes several minutes to get ~15 mobs, and it never seems to go above that amount. My view distance is set to 16, and I don't think I have any rules issues as I am getting spawns, just super slowly.

Does anyone know why my nether mobs are spawning so slowly? Being a skyblock world, there is no other land in render distance so it's not an issue of mobs spawning elsewhere.

Comment: A world download could help here.

Comment: What is the preferred way to share a world file?

Comment: Upload it anywhere, for example Dropbox or Google Drive, and link it.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ys207f6b3j3ul38/Skyblock%204.02.zip?dl=0
Playing in 1.13.2

Comment: Why are you playing in 1.13.2? 1.15.2 is better in every way.

Comment: You mean the area aroud -50 0 in the Nether? There's simply not much space. Not every spot gets flooded with mobs instantly.

Comment: I have a similar mob farm in the overworld that spawns mobs much more quickly. And I'm not talking instantly, I've sat there for 10 minutes or more and it stays around 15-16 mobs.
I'm staying in 1.13.2 for the old villager trading system, for now.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of things, including disabling the datapack, but I can't find the reason. From what I found in the wiki, this shouldn't happen. But I can definitely confirm that it does.

Comment: Actually, one last thing: Try placing more blocks around the area in the Nether. They don't need to be valid spawn spaces, but this might increase the potential starting locations for a pack spawn, of which then more mobs can end up inside your spawnable area.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for taking a look. I actually plan to build a larger flying machine based farm, but I wasn't sure I wanted to go through all the effort if spawn rates were going to be so bad, but maybe a larger room would be better than the two strips.

Comment: That as well, yes. But I'm still interested in why this happens. I actually meant more non-spawnable blocks **outside** the dark room.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I think you're referring to how pack spawning behavior works, right? I guess the other thing is once a few mobs are in the farm, the likelihood of the rest of the spawning spaces being selected becomes a lot lower. I hadn't been thinking of these details, though I am somewhat familiar with them.

Answer (score -1):

unless I misunderstood, you made 1 block wide spawning areas? (Comment if you meant something different)
I'm fairly sure the most efficient spawn area is 9x3x9.

Edit:
Sorry, I thought you meant farming blaze spawners.

Edit 2, Attempt at redemption:
I checked out the world file and I can sort of see why it wasn't spawning much, the whole spawning area is two (1,1,30) columns which, even with them being the only spots spawning, is a tiny space for a mob farm,[image] I'd go for Fabian Roling's suggestion (see below) and do his circle with radius 128 and more platforms thinger, also I'd recommend looking at the mob farm wiki for some ideas [(the wiki)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Mob_farm).

Anyway, I hope I wasn't a complete waste of time, and I hope you have make a successful mob farm.

Comment: The most efficient spawn area would be a circle with radius 128 and more platforms within that 128m radius sphere. I don't know where you got 9×3×9 from.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought they meant spawners.

Comment: Even then it's not correct.

Comment: Ok fine, I admit it I'm a noob.

Comment: Oh, it's for a fortress, I forgot. Then it's of course not useful to have a spawning platform outside the fortress boundaries. But I don't know where they are, I think you can only figure that out with spawning tests or by looking at the world save in NBTExplorer and even then it's difficult to get the exact correct position.

Comment: Thanks guys. I did add non-spawnable blocks around the farm after this, and it did increase the rates somewhat. I've long since moved on from this world though... :)